# indexing array in python

Tags: python, arrays, indexing

I have an array of the following format:

```
[[['roll', 'around', 'heavy', 'thing'], 'friction'], 
 [['chop', 'piece', 'rubber', 'stuff', 'playground'], 'source'],
 [['ball', 'play', 'pet'], 'toy'], 
 [['used', 'exercise', 'yoga', 'pilate'], 'toy']]]
```

First, I am trying to index the second piece of each element, here that would be `friction`, `source`, `toy` and `toy` and secondly also individual strings of the first parts, like `around` or `thing`.

No matter what I try I can either only index the entire element `[[word, word, word], word]` or get a `list indices must be integers, not tuple` error message.

---

I tried `training_set [0]`, which gives the first full element. `training_set [0][1]`, which gives me the second element of the first list (`'friction'` here) I can also get specific elements of the first list with `training_set [0][0][0]`. And from here on I'm stuck, as I'm trying to get ALL elements of a particular subset.

Comment: Can you show your attempt?

Comment: I tried training_set [0], which gives the first full element.
training_set [0][1], which gives me the second element of the first list ('friction' here)
I can also get specific elements of the first list with training_set [0][0][0].

And from here on I'm stuck, as I'm trying to get ALL elements of a particular subset.

Comment: Edit your question to include your attempts - showing us what you've tried and what you expected. Usually, this lets us see what you are misunderstanding and we can then offer an explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use multiple *chained* indexes, like:

```
 >>> your_list[0][1]
 'friction'
```

or loops to access with variable index:

```
>>> for sublist in your_list:
...    print(sublist[1])
friction
source
toy
toy
```

Additionally you can access slices of one sublist. For example to get elements 2,3,4 from the first sublist you can use `your_list[0][0][2:5]`.

But it's not possible to simultaneously access elements from different sublists without explicit (`for`) or implicit (`map`) loop.

Comment: Is there a way of getting those sublists though, without using the loop? Say I just want to be able to use all sublist elements with a single index.